# Python Scrapy, include text, exclude text using xpath

Tags: python, xml, xpath, scrapy

So I am using Scrapy at the moment and want to scrape a website for specific information. I want to be able to ONLY scrape information if certain text is present, but also only scrape information if certain text isn't present.

For example, I may look for apple, banana or pear and want to scrape the pages if I find one of the words present, but if peach is in the text too, I do not want to scrape the content. I hope that makes sense?

As I understand it, I can use xpath to create an or statement like this:

```
//tbody[contains(text(), "apple")] | //tbody[contains(text(), "banana")] | //tbody[contains(text(), "pear")]
```

but how would I tell Xpath to not scrape the page if it finds peach in there?

There are also a few other elements I'm pulling from the page too, but I don't think they're relevant (please tell me if I'm wrong)

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use the `not` XPath function as follows:

```
//tbody[not(contains(text(), "peach"))]
```

You could combine two expressions as follows:

```
//tbody[contains(text(), "apple") and not(contains(text(), "peach"))]
```

This would select the table bodies that include `apple`, but not `pear`. Note, you can use the period character `.` as an alternative for `text()`.

Comment: Thanks so much, I'll mark it as the answer as soon as it'll let me. I knew it'd be simple, but I'm stepping into a whole new world with Xpath, and taking baby steps.I actually want to try and run some stats which eBay uk can't provide via the API to do with shipping in relation to 'who's the favourite carrier' and also looking into if there's direct correlation between carrier and poor/neutral feedback. This will help me get a little further :)

Comment: Yeah, I'm hoping it will be, but I know the eBay site is a tricky one to negotiate. The reason I asked about excluding an entry is because I don't want to include Royal Mail at this time due to the majority being sent with them, and I want to limit the scraping in tests :) A quick question though, you said I can combine expressions, could I say `//tbody[contains(text(), "apple", "pear", "banana") and not contains(text(), "peach", "starfruit")] `

Comment: Note that the period character `.` is not an alternative for `text()` in XPath. `.` is short the context node, `text()` is a node test for text nodes (character data, between tags). `contains(text(), "something")` tests if the context node has its first child text node containing "something". `contains(., "something")` will test if the string representation of the context node contains "something" (I think this is what you want/need)